# Run SH file from Resourse in jar

Tags: java, bash, jar

Can I run SH file that finds in the JAR?

I am trying to pull the file from resources and shove it into the process.

```
                String fileName = command[0];
                ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();

                File file = new File(classLoader.getResource(fileName).getFile());

                List<String> temp = new ArrayList<>();

                temp.add("sh");
                temp.add(file.getPath());
                temp.addAll(Arrays.stream(command).filter(s -> !s.contains(".sh")).collect(Collectors.toList()));

                String[] stringExec = new String[temp.size()];

                for (int i = 0; i < stringExec.length; i++)
                    stringExec[i] = temp.get(i);

//                Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(stringExec);


                Path script = Files.createTempFile(null, ".sh",
                        PosixFilePermissions.asFileAttribute(
                                PosixFilePermissions.fromString("rw-rw-r--")));

                    Files.copy(file.toPath(), script, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);

                String[] cmd = { "bash", script.toString() };

                ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(cmd);
                builder.inheritIO();

                Process process = builder.start();
                process.waitFor();

                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

                BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new
                        InputStreamReader(process.getErrorStream()));

                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    CustomLog.log(line, TypeLog.LOG);
                }

                while ((line = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
                    CustomLog.log(line, TypeLog.WARN);
                }

                Files.delete(script);
```

When I try to run in this way, I gives me an error

```
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: file:/root/Documents/module.jar!/file.sh
```

Or just if the external file then I can execute it?

Answer (score 1):

I doubt `Files.copy` will copy a file out of a jar. I'd suggest using `ClassLoader.getRessourceAsStream` and do a stream copy to the temp file.